# making a string into a list within a list comprehension

Tags: python

What is asked:
By filtering the lowers list, create a list of the words which are at least 5 letters long and which have their letters already in alphabetical order.

What I have:

```
[word for word in lowers if len(word)>= 5 and word.sort=word]
```

I know that this will not work because the word.sort is being used on a string and word needs to be a list to make this function work. How would I do this in side the list comprehension or do i need to define something before.

Comment: Even if `word` were a list, this still wouldn't work, because `sort` sorts the list destructively and returns `None`. So you'd need to use `sorted` instead (or one of the other solutions).

Comment: Also, you're mixing up `=` and `==`, so you'd get a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use list comprehension:

```
[word for word in lowers if len(word)>=5 and sorted(word)==list(word)]
```

Another is to use Python 2's [**filter**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) function for stuff like this. Also, this uses string.join to convert sorted list back to string

```
#Lambda function to test condition
test = lambda x: len(x)>=5 and ''.join(sorted(x))==x
#Returns list of elements for which test is True
filter(test, lowers)
```

Plain ol' function (bonus: [generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and [yield](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-yield_stmt)!):

```
def filterwords(lst):
    for word in lst:
        if len(word)>=5 and sorted(word)==list(word):
            yield word
```

The last one is most efficient, resource-wise and such.

---

Update: .sort() can be used on lists (not strings) to sort a list directly, but it does not return a value. So, `list(word).sort()` is of no use here; we use `sorted(word)`.

```
>>> lst = [1,100,10]
>>> sorted(lst) #returns sorted list
[1, 10, 100]
>>> lst #is still the same
[1, 100, 10]
>>> lst.sort() #returns nothing
>>> lst #has updated
[1, 10, 100]
```

Comment: +1 for explaining all the possibiities, with pros and cons for each. It might be worth explaining that `word.sort()` wouldn't work even if `word` were a `list` instead of a `str`, but otherwise, this is as complete as could be, and very concise.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> sorted('foo') == list('foo')
True
>>> sorted('bar') == list('bar')
False
```